# Composer install Laravel asks for authentication for Github

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

When I try to install a Laravel project from a composer.lock file, Composer prompts me for authentication.

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
  - Installing laravel/framework (v4.1.21)
    Authentication required (api.github.com):
      Username:

$ composer --version
Composer version 7343198817f365b1676ced0f353808f0e408ff9a 2014-02-07 09:59:35

$ php -i | grep ssl
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls
openssl
```

I have OpenSSL installed. Using PHP 5.5.3 on Ubuntu 13.10.

Any idea how to get around this? Tried to give it my Github credentials, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Happens a lot with Composer.

This is a temporary composer/packagist problem: it's not being able to download required files (usually due to timeout) and when file access is 'denied' it asks for the VCS password.

Comment: Thanks, I will wait and see.

Comment: Using Composer a lot in a short time might trigger the Github API limit. You could simply sign up and use that account to increase the limit.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue and a coworker suggested to run:

```
composer install --prefer-source
```

which will **git clone**

Description:

> Forces installation from package sources when possible, including VCS information.

He also noted that:

```
composer install --prefer-dist
```

will download a zipped version of the package.

Description:

> Forces installation from package dist even for dev versions.

In either case, the API is **not** used.