# laravel homestead cannot create project

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I have download homestead box manually, and add it to vagrant like: "vagrant box add laravel/homestead virtualbox.box".
Then I run command "vagrant init laravel/homestead" to create a new development environment. 
Now I can start the virtual machine by "vagrant up". 
I login into the new virtual machine by "vagrant ssh". 
I run command "composer create-project laravel/laravel new-site" to create new project, but it always give error that authentication required (packagelist.org)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630806/composer-install-laravel-asks-for-authentication-for-github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you setting up your SSH keys in the Homestead.yaml file?? It's necessary to add this SSH keys.

For that you can also prefer this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#installation-and-setup

May be it's helpfull for you..!!

Comment: Please give upvote if this answer helpfull. :)@richard