# Authentication required (packagist.org) Laravel installation

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to install Laravel (any version). Actually I cloned from GitHub the Laravel project (https://github.com/laravel/laravel) After cloning I'm running the command as below:

```
root:/var/www/html/laravel$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Authentication required (packagist.org): 
  Username:
```

This is the issue I'm facing, I don't know what username I have to give, and why its asking authentication.. And if I run `composer diagnose` I get this output:

```
composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: Authentication required    (packagist.org):
  Username:
```

Any suggestions or can anyone tell what was I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy of some kind ? Did you try composer install -vvv to get more debug ?

Comment: please refer this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630806/composer-install-laravel-asks-for-authentication-for-github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630806/composer-install-laravel-asks-for-authentication-for-github)

Comment: Thank you for replying, i run the command composer install -vvv but in the middle i got the below shown error `[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                    
  Invalid credentials for 'http://packagist.org/p/symfony/polyfill-mbstring%24c9c4d394bcfc0f197c6dd5c0524fa35a32f2dd07a0c9d208d04811248115b0  
  e6.json', aborting.` dont know what to do now... any other suggestions

Answer (score 20):

run `composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org` and then try again. This should prevent it from using http protocol and force https which might fix it in case you have a bad proxy in the way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, solved the issue as below:

```
$ composer diagnose

Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: FAIL
Missing pubkey for tags verification
Missing pubkey for dev verification
Run composer self-update --update-keys to set them up
Checking composer version: WARNING
You are not running the latest stable version, run `composer self-update` to update (1.6.3 => 1.7.2)
Composer version: 1.6.3
PHP version: 7.2.8
PHP binary path: /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.8/bin/php
```

The I ran

```
$ composer self-update --update-keys

Open https://composer.github.io/pubkeys.html to find the latest keys
Enter Dev / Snapshot Public Key (including lines with -----): 
[copy and paste the dev pub key]

Enter Tags Public Key (including lines with -----):
[copy and paste the tags pub key]
```

Then again, I ran

```
$ composer self-update
```

However, during installing the package, it still shows:

```
Authentication required (repo.packagist.org):
  Username:
```

After providing my username and password for my packagist.org account and having my credential stored in `/Users/xxx/.composer/auth.json`, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this `composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org` first on your CLI

Comment: So it looks like you copied the same answer as the currently most-voted answer to the question. Is there any thing extra you are able to add to support your answer?